# Let $f: G \rightarrow G'$ be a homomorphism. If $G$ is infinite, and $G'$ is finite, then can $\ker(f)$ be finite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $f: G \rightarrow G'$ be a homomorphism. If $G$ is infinite, and $G'$ is finite, then can $\ker(f)$ be finite?

I believe the answer is no, since by the first isomorphism theorem $G/\ker(f) \cong G'$, which implies that $|G/\ker(f)| = |G'| \rightarrow |G|/|\ker(f)| = |G'|$ by Lagrange, which implies that $|G| = |\ker(f)||G'|$, which is a contradiction if $|\ker(f)|$ is finite.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct: a homomorphism of an infinite group $G$ with a finite image must "kill" all but finitely many elements in $G$.

Comment: Your reasoning is almost entirely correct, but it seems that you assumed that the image of $f$ is all of $G'$.  You instead have $\text{Im}(f) \leq G'$, so $|\mathrm{Im}(f)| \leq |G'|$ and your argument carries through.

Comment: Ah, I see the mistake now. Thank you!

Comment: There is a subtle mistake still. You are dealing with infinite numbers, better *cardinals*. Hence, you cannot divide like you can with finite numbers. So be careful. You should approach this from a set theoretic point of view. $ker(f)$ is a subgroup and the group $G$ can be written as a union of cosets of this subgroup, etc., etc.